# Can't add private repository to Matlab Source Control

Tags: git, matlab, github

I'm trying to add my github repository to Matlab R2021a using their source control menu and it doesn't work. How do I actually make the connection? I'm unable to add the repository when it is configured as a private repository, but the second I switch it to public I'm able to connect. This is using the GitHub Teams license, since this is in a corporate environment.

When it is a private repository Matlab will repeatedly ask me for a username and password, it will eventually fail. I know for a fact that I'm inputting the correct login information. For fun I tried logging in with a random username and the error is exactly the same. The exact error is:

> Unable to validate the specified path with the following git error: https://github.com/my-user-name/Test_2: not authorized.

My steps:
Project tab -> Source Control -> Remote -> (enter git https URL) -> validate

I tried starting it as a public repository, making the connection, and then changing it to private, to see if it would hold the connection. That did not work.

I'm separately having issues with SSH setup. According to [this article](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/494543-why-do-i-receive-an-auth-fail-error-when-interacting-with-a-git-remote-over-ssh-in-matlab-or-why-d?s_tid=srchtitle), setting up SSH is a lost cause for R2021a.

Comment: Is this a rant or is there a question hidden in there? If things don’t work as documented, why don’t you contact your MATLAB representative? You pay for the tool, customer service is part of that deal.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication (2FA) activated for GitHub? If yes, you need to use a PAT instead of your password.

Answer (score 1):

Matt was correct, I had to use a personal access token to connect to the private repository.